# Android AVD not showing anything. only "ANDROID" in the middle of the screen

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am an Android Newbie! please help.

I have been following googles introduction tutorial and managed to install everything with no problems. but whenever i try to run the HelloAndroid example the avd launches but doesnt show anything.

cone somebody help please?

Comment: how long have you waited? AVD loading is quite long.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After you create an AVD it really does take a long time to initialize. On my less than year old Core2Duo 2.8 GHz running Win7x64 and 4Gb of RAM, initializing a 2.2 version took at least 5 to 10 minutes (if not longer). Once it starts initializing you can watch the logcat in the DDMS panel of eclipse and watch it unpack and install all of the apps in the emulator.

Comment: This was also helpful for me. 5-10 minutes is unexpected lang so I thought that something is wrong or has to be adjusted.

Comment: It takes almost longer than this on my FX-8350 (8 cores at 4.4 GHz overclocked) with 14GB of RAM

Comment: It has been more than 15 minutes since I launched emulator .should I wait?,Dual Core,2GB ram

Comment: @KartikWatwani If you can connect to emulator via adb - look at what logcat is generated.If its moving/unpacking you may want to wait else kill it and try again with lower device specs on emulator (i.e. 640x480 screen).

Comment: @MorrisonChang I will try.

Answer (score 9):

It is quicker to export the file to your phone using USB cable, install it by selecting the `.apk` file with a file manager and run it from your phone. This also gives you "real" simulations of the app. It is quicker also. If your app has flaws, it is quicker to find them on your phone then wait for the AVD to load only to find your app doesn't work!

1. Goto *File -> Export*, select android folder then android application.
2. On the next page, select the application you want to export.
3. Create a keyfile and an alias.
4. Eject your phone, then open your file manager of choice, and click on the app.
5. Run using android package installer, you will need to enable no market application install in your settings
6. Open the app after the install is complete.

Comment: Using a 'real' phone is indeed much quicker. Using Android Studio I don't have to carry out any of these steps. I just ensure my phone has USB Debugging switched on and then Android Studio detects it and offers it as an option when I 'Run' the app.

Answer (score 7):

You can always run 'adb shell' or 'adb logcat' from another window to see what is happening...

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem but I fixed it by deleting **.android** folder from C:\Users\User\

Now everytime I start Eclipse or AVD, I delete that folder. After that everything works charm.

**OPTIONAL :** If the problem still persists, try to clone the NEXUS S AVD.

Answer (score 1):

How long did you wait for it?  On my (admittedly older and slower) home computer, it can take some time for the AVD to initialize the first time.  I've just tried it and it takes about 90 seconds for the "ANDROID" in the center of the screen to be replaced with the home screen, then about another 30 seconds for the application to run.

Comment: thanks mate, it was just me being inpatient lol i am also using a quite dated laptop just for the dev.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. It was because i hadn't restarted my system after installing ADT plugin. It worked fine after restarting my system.

Answer (score 0):

Occasionally i've found that it just hangs up on the loading screen, and if you restart it, it comes right. Also, from memory it can take awful long to load first time.

Comment: thanks for the advice, my laptop is a little old and it is just a matter of time before it comes up, cheers

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu (I use Xubuntu):

Mine Android Virtual Devices didn't started because i used NVIDIA drivers for ubuntu. After changing drivers to Nouveau it booted in 15sec.

Go to "Settings Manager" -> Software & Updated -> Additional Drivers chose: "Using X.org x server -- Nouveau display driver (open source)"

NVIDIA F# U http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55XVnJ_0qhg

Answer (score 0):

Yeah It took too much time to start....
Try Switching on Visualization in the system BIOS Settings....
For me before switching it didn't show up anything. After changing it took 3 mins to initiate

System Specs:
*i5 Dual Core
4Gb
Nvidia 2G*

Answer (score 0):

Stop the emulator --> Open ADV Manager --> Edit the Virtual device --> Click Show Advanced Settings --> Set the Ram size 512mb --> Start the emulator