# In my eclipse ADT, default xml editor is not opening and virtual device manager wizard is also not opening

Tags: android, android-emulator

In my eclipse ADT, default xml editor is not opening showing 
"Could not open the editor: An unexpected exception was thrown."
 and also virtual device manager wizard is also not opening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your Eclipse settings got corrupted or something. I'd try switching the workspace, and if that doesn't work, redownload/reinstall Eclipse and ADT.

Answer (score 0):

By default editor, do you mean the eclipse editor?
Also check the AVD properties.
And refer this question, it might help.

[Android AVD not showing anything. only "ANDROID" in the middle of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692363/android-avd-not-showing-anything-only-android-in-the-middle-of-the-screen)