# Opening android XML file shows NullpointerException in newly installed Eclipse

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

Please give me a solution .
My problem is,the **xml** files are not opens from my eclipse editor and there is no response when I run a Application program from eclipse .The eclipse is newly installed one

This is the screenshot when opening a xml file ..

[image]

Comment: Please post the relevant bit of the error log.

Comment: check this it may help u. . .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14168542/in-my-eclipse-adt-default-xml-editor-is-not-opening-and-virtual-device-manager

Comment: @Simon There is no error log shows in log cat and there is no response when i run this app.. Plz note That Eclipse is newly configured..

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something is wrong with the default xml editor.
Right-Mouse-Click the xml file in the Package-Explorer and then "Open With".
This should give you a number of different options to open the xml file.