# Android AVD screen appears blank

Tags: android

I have started learning android myself, I have setup the enivronment I am following [this](http://www.javatpoint.com/hello-android-example) link, I have successfully created Hello World app,but when I am running it,the AVD is appearing with black screen with just android word on it.
[image]

I have followed each step mentioned in the link,but no luck there is no error in console too, I saw solution in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23465903/android-avd-emulator-in-eclipse-shows-black-screen-and-android) link and I have waited so too long but its still showing just android word and not Hello world.
Also Please suggest some good book/tutorial for android

Comment: Your AVD is normal. It's just booting. You should wait until home app to be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is the intro of the emulator for some reason your emulator cannot starts,restart your emulator or create a new one.  I recommend you use GenyMotion for Android emulator . Some good tutorials for android:

http://developer.android.com/index.html , http://www.androidhive.info/ , http://www.vogella.com/

Comment: Thanks,btw I am using eclipse of Java is it correct version or shall I install eclipse of Java EE?

Comment: I have deleted and created emulator twice but still same issue

Comment: You should use Android Studio !

Answer (score 1):

Restart your AVD, it takes some time in the beginning. You need to have patience and wait till the home page comes in the emulator. If this doesn't work try to use another  Android AVD as mentioned in the above ans.

Also you should prefer **Android Studio** over eclipse.