# Can't run emulators on a PC with Core 2 cpu

Tags: android-emulator

For the last few days I had been searching all over the internet for an answer as to why I can't run emulators on my computer. Turns out that Intel HAXM is not supported on the Core 2 architecture.

Does anyone know if I can somehow make emulators run, despite those limitations?

Comment: Honestly you would be better off debugging/testing with a physical device. While emulators of the time worked, they were slow.and even things like changing to a smaller screen resolution (say 640x480) made a performance difference. So HAXM today is a preferred solution. See my [old answer to AVD startup time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3693851/295004).

Comment: That's what I have been doing actualy, since I cant run emulators I am running my apps on a physical device. I was thinking that it would be less of a hassle doing the testing inside of a emulator, but now that you pointed out how slow they actualy are, I might well be better of sticking to a phisical device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there really isn't a workaround for this problem. The only solution is to simply use a phisical device.